# How to send data to another mobile in windows phone from server?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am developing an app in windows phone where I enter the score of the match and the other windows phone users who has the same app should get that score as a toast notification(if any other better way suggest me).

I also want to push the data to this app users from a rss feed. This feed gets refreshed data for every 1 or 2 mins.

IS this possible to implement this in windows phone ?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. You will need to use a Push Notification service to push stuff to the phone or a background task polling a web service of yours to do this. Direct implementation details are up to you. You will need a web service in the middle somewhere though.

Comment: I have used Background agents earlier .but they will trigger only for every 30 mins. So it's of no use to me.My RSS feed gets refreshed data for every 30mins. So I am looking for something where I can send  a notification to the user from this rss feed whenever the score is updated. For e.g. in Tennis match for ever few seconds game point changes (1-0, 1-1 or 2-0 etc)

Comment: the only way you can do that would be to use the `Push Notification` service.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to send the notification of the match score to certain users then you could use [Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx).

If everyone needs to get the notification then you would just use a [BackgroundAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The Background agent will run approximately every 30 minutes (if you need it to be more accurate then you're back to Push Notifications). When the agent runs you could just check to see if there are any new match scores since the time the agent last ran and then pop the toast if there are.

You should also use the Background Agent for checking your RSS feed.

Comment: But they can be triggered only for 30 mins. I am looking for something where a service in cloud or somewhere which can help us push the data to phone very frequently.

Comment: Then use Push Notifications.